# Rails join two tables based on relation in third

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to join 2 tables, but I need to use 3th to set a relation between them.

Each Order is prepared by an Employee. I want to find OrderDetails only for specific employees. To check that, I need to find who was assigned to shop orders.

I'm almost sure that I know how to do it in SQL. Just concept query:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.payment_id FROM OrderDetais
    INNER JOIN ShopOrders ON ShopOrders.id = OrderDetails.shop_order_id
    INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.id = ShopOrders.employee_id
WHERE Employees.id IN (5, 6, 8)
```

I'm just trying to write the same in Rails:

```
query = OrderDetail
        .where('order_details.created_at > ? AND order_details.created_at < ?', 1.year.ago, 2.days.ago)
query = query.joins(:shop_order)
```

I use `to_sql` to check if my query looks good. Everything goes ok, until I join `query.joins(: employee)`

```
query = OrderDetail
        .where('order_details.created_at > ? AND order_details.created_at < ?', 1.year.ago, 2.days.ago)
query = query.joins(:shop_order)
query = query.joins(:employee)
```

then I receive an error:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'OrderDetail' to association named 'employee'; perhaps you misspelled it?>

I tried to follow [Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-multiple-level). But I don't know how to use it properly.

In OrderDetail model there is:

`delegate :employee, to: :shop_order, allow_nil: true`

In ShopOrder model:

```
  belongs_to :employee, optional: false
  has_many :order_details, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

And Employee model:

```
  has_many :shop_orders
  has_many :order_details, through: :shop_orders
```

Answer (score 2):

Basing on the 'Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)' reference you provided the following should do what you want:

```rb
query
  .joins(shop_orders: :employee)
  .where(employees: { id: [5, 6, 8] })
```

Comment: I saw this in documentation, but I receive same error "Can't join 'OrderDetail' to association named 'employee'; `

Comment: @eudaimonia there is no way you received that error if you used the solution provided in this answer. If anything it would be `Can't join 'ShopOrder' to association named 'employee'` which also would not occur based on your post

Comment: yes second one. but `.joins(shop_order: :employee)` fixed that

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it like that:

```
query.joins(:shop_order)
     .joins('JOIN employees ON employees.id = shop_orders.employee_id')
     .where(employees: { id: [5, 6, 8] })
```